# requestExportSessionForVideo null error

Tags: ios, video, phasset

I am using the requestExportSessionForVideo method to get a sendable video from a PHAsset, but I am getting this warning, and the export session logs a null value:

```
Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
```

Here is the method call:

```
[manager requestExportSessionForVideo:asset options:videoOptions exportPreset:AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown resultHandler:^(AVAssetExportSession * _Nullable exportSession, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            NSLog(@"Export session is: %@ ///// Info is %@", exportSession, info);
        }];
```

The info that is printed looks good however:

```
Info is {
PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey = "8b504346993c71de48743d3c9c796385d7911ad2;00000000;00000000;000000000000001b;com.apple.avasset.read-only;00000001;01000002;00000000000468eb;/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0004.MOV";
PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 20000;
PHImageResultIsInCloudKey = 0;
PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 20000;
}
```

How can I get a video object from a PHAsset that I can send to a cloud container?
Will this warning affect the output?
Please note my assets are selected using the GMImagePicker.

Comment: You need to change AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown to some const like AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality

Answer (score 3):

This might help you to proceed further. I'm currently facing same issue. but following method gives me Video URL.

```
PHVideoRequestOptions* options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
    options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
    options.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeAutomatic;
    options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
    options.progressHandler =  ^(double progress,NSError *error,BOOL* stop, NSDictionary* dict) {
        NSLog(@"progress %lf",progress);  //never gets called
    };


[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset* avasset, AVAudioMix* audioMix, NSDictionary* info){
        NSLog(@"##Info:\n%@",info);
        AVURLAsset* myAsset = (AVURLAsset*)avasset;
        NSLog(@"##AVAsset URL: %@",myAsset.URL);
    }];
```

OUTPUT

```
2015-11-25 12:00:04.482 iLockBox[7602:2587808] ##Info:
{
    PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey = "7c2094f4c69015b87df6d7c86ec3217cc544e2e2;00000000;00000000;000000000000001b;com.apple.avasset.read-only;00000001;01000002;0000000000ff9a15;/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/111APPLE/IMG_1087.MOV";
    PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 20000;
    PHImageResultIsInCloudKey = 0;
    PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 20000;
}
2015-11-25 12:00:16.007 iLockBox[7602:2587808] ##AVAsset URL: file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/111APPLE/IMG_1087.MOV
```

**please comment your result.**

Comment: you basically cannot do much with file path since you do not have any permission to read the file.

Answer (score 3):

Swift - Here, solution for getting video url using requestAVAssetForVideo... its working for me ...

```
let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
options.version = .Original
options.deliveryMode = .Automatic
options.networkAccessAllowed = true

PHCachingImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(asset, options: options, resultHandler:
                                {
                                    (avAsset, audioMix, info) in

                                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                                        let theAsset = avAsset as! AVURLAsset
                                        let videoURL = theAsset.URL
                                        print(videoURL)

                                    })
                            })
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version of @Pankaj's working answer for convenience

```
let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
options.version = .original
options.deliveryMode = .automatic
options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

PHCachingImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: phAsset, options: options, resultHandler:{ (avAsset, audioMix, info) in

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          let theAsset = avAsset as! AVURLAsset
          let videoURL = theAsset.url
          print(videoURL)
       }
})
```