# BookmarkHow to use PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestAvAsset correctly? AvAsset is always null

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, avasset, photokit, phimagemanager

***asset*** is not null but ***avAsset*** always comes up as null. That's why I can't get video url. How can I fix this?

```
var vOptions = new PHVideoRequestOptions();
vOptions.NetworkAccessAllowed = true;
vOptions.Version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersion.Original;
vOptions.DeliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.FastFormat;

PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestAvAsset(asset, vOptions, (avAsset, audioMix, vInfo) =>
{
   if (avAsset != null)
   {
      videoUrl = ((AVFoundation.AVUrlAsset)avAsset).Url.Path;
   }
});

await Task.Delay(5000);
```

Comment: Can you please have a try with `PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionCurrent`? And do you have a video there?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I tried but the result did not change

Comment: Well your codes looks code, how about implementing `options.progressHandler`  as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33909949/10539446). I will test and update you if I find anything.

Comment: Hi @JackHua-MSFT I have same problem. How can i implement ProgressHandler to xamarin ios. I went your suggested thread but I didn't change it to Xamarin.iOS codes.

Comment: You mean you have difficulty translate oc to c#? You can open a new thread and we will support you there.